# Format part of the column value in a ListView Web Part

Tags: jquery

I have a list containing a few items, some of which are marked as compliant. So I have a column for marking it as compliant, and another calculated column, where I have the calculated value as *Title (Compliant)*

Now, I am showing this data on a page using a ListView Web Part. 
My requirement is that the Web Part should display the text as *Title **(Compliant)***, ie., the text *Compliant* should be formatted such that it stands out from the rest of the text.

How can I achieve this?

**Update:**
I have the below code in a js file linked from a CEWP on my page, but it is throwing some errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $body = $('body');
  var html = $body.html();
  var newHtml = html.replace(/\(Compliant\)/g, '<span style="font-weight:bold;">(Compliant)</span>');
  $body.html(newHtml);
});
</script>
```

The errors are as below:

```
Message: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once. Line: 688 Char: 13 Code: 0 URI: http://mysite/ScriptResource.axd?d=..   
Message: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. Line: 2 Char: 2568 Code: 0 URI: http://mysite/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js   
Message: 'childNodes' is null or not an object Line: 5246 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI: http://mysite/_layouts/1033/init.debug.js?rev=..
```

Comment: The code seems correct to me. What's the error been thrown exactly?

Comment: The first error has nothing to do with jquery. I wonder how you added jquery to the masterpage and where and when you are calling the code you showed

Comment: I have updated the question with more details of the code and the error.

Comment: The first error is quite descriptive. How and where did you add jquery to the page?

Comment: I have put the above code in a js file, and linked to the js file from a CEWP at the end of the page.

Comment: having read your code a second time, I think I know where the problem lies. Let me do some tests and I'll come back with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is modifying the calculated column so that it can emit html formatted string directly.

Change the return type of your calculated column to Number, then edit the formula to something like:

```
="<span class='fixMyHead'>" & Title & " <b>(Compliant)</b></span>"
```

Now, in order to left-align the column td and th, you can use a bit of jQuery:

```
$('.fixMyHead').each(function(){  
    $td = $(this).parents('td:first');   
    $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index()).find('.ms-numHeader').css('text-align', 'left');
    $td.children(':first').css('text-align', 'left');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Md.. 
That was a fast hack, but now I have a problem that the column is right aligned, as its type is 'Number'.

Also, I was putting off the html thing for later, as I wanted the calculated column to link to the Dispform.aspx for the record; but I would need the correct ID and ListID for that.

Comment: You can link to the DispForm in SPD easily. Edit your view, select your calc field, then right click, then Format item as > Hyperlink to > Display form

Comment: I added a quick fix of the text alignment

Comment: Thanks Md. I was able to get everything working as needed, with slight changes to the jQuery snippet you shared.

Comment: I tried your suggestion regarding linking to the DispForm. It works fine in the list view page; however, in my ListView Web Part, the links are lost.

I get this message when I try to change the view in the Web Part: `Switching to a different view removes changes you have made to this view, and may disable Web Part connections that depend on columns in this view.` Could this be the problem?

Comment: If you're not using connections, then try to switch the view to the one you edited. It should work

Comment: When I create a view including the calculated column, and modify it to link to the Display form, it works fine on my List View Page. However, when I add a ListView Web Part on my home page, and set the 'Selected View' as the new view created, the links from the calculated columns are gone. And I am not using any connections on the Web Part.

Comment: You can save the customized xsl in a stylesheet file into a document library, then use it for the XSL property of the webpart on the homepage. See this link for guidance on this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2012/10/23/guidance-for-xsllink-property-with-the-xsltlistviewwebpart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint are you using?

If you’re using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to look at the rendering possibilities with JSLink. JSLink is perfect for conditional formatting.